# Algorithm to recursively create a fully parenthesized expression from an expression tree

Tags: java, recursion

I know to do an inorder traversal, but I can't figure out how to differentiate left children from right children.  Should I even be basing when to put parentheses in on leaves or should I be doing something else.  I'm awful with recursion.  I already have the tree working perfectly, so I can put in an expression like (1 + 2) * (3 - 4), convert it to postfix and add it to a tree.  I just need to find a way to give each expression its own set of parentheses.

This is the code that made it work, thanks for the algorithm dreamcrash!

```
private void printInfix(Node n)
{   
    if (n != null)
    {
        if (n.isLeaf())//if n is a leaf, therefore a number
            System.out.print(n.element);
        else//n is not a leaf
        {
            System.out.print("(");
            printInfix(n.left);
            System.out.print(n.element);
            printInfix(n.right);
            System.out.print(")");
        }//end else
    }//end if   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some research and I found this:

```
Algorithm infix (tree)
/*Print the infix expression for an expression tree.
 Pre : tree is a pointer to an expression tree
 Post: the infix expression has been printed*/
 if (tree not empty)
    if (tree token is operand)
       print (tree token)
    else
       print (open parenthesis)
       infix (tree left subtree)
       print (tree token)
       infix (tree right subtree)
       print (close parenthesis)
    end if
 end if
end infix
```

on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree.

I also found a good explanation and some code implementation (but in python). Nevertheless, the idea remains the same, it is just a matter of syntax: http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Trees/bintreeapps.html

Answer (score 0):

You should add the parentheses in a parent node, not the child node. As you stated, you are having trouble telling a right child from a left child. This is because the child node doesn't know which it is. However, a parent node has this information right at hand.